# Select from two tables where company_id=$company->id

Tags: php, mysql, select, joomla

hello I have this variable `$company->id`

and I have function like this

```
<?php 
function GetEmploees(){
   $db = JFactory::getDBO();
   $query = 'SELECT * FROM #__jbusinessdirectory_attribute_options AS c JOIN #__jbusinessdirectory_company_attributes AS cp
   on c.id  = cp.option_id';

   $db->setQuery($query);

   if( $rows = $db->loadObjectList() ) {
     foreach( $rows as $row ){ 
       echo $row->name;
     }
   }
}

echo GetEmploees($company->id);

?>
```

I want select `$row->name` as `$company->id`

how can I insert code `WHERE company_id = '.$company->id.'` in query?

`company_id` is in table `#__jbusinessdirectory_company_attributes`

Answer (score 0):

Try

`$sql = "SELECT * FROM #__jbusinessdirectory_attribute_options AS c INNER JOIN #__jbusinessdirectory_company_attributes AS cp (on c.id  = cp.option_id) WHERE c.company_id = '.$company->id.'";`

Should do the trick

Comment: Try changing your function to `function GetEmploees($id){` and `$company->id` in the query to just `$id`

Comment: That simply means your SQL query has an error, double check your query syntax